# Can't build Angular 9 project on RHEL 8 with FIPS enabled

Tags: angular, fips

We need to use RHEL 8 with Angular 9. By default RHEL 8 has FIPS enabled. When trying to build an Angular 9 application get the error below. Tried setting FIPS=0 but it messes up many of the java libraries. In RHEL 7 we could set FIPS=0 to build, but not with RHEL 8.

I believe this is because it's using the md5 hash algorithm, which is not FIPS compliant.

- If this is true, how to select a different hash algorithm?
- If not, how to successfully build with FIPS enabled?

```
Error: error:060800C8:digital envelope routines:EVP_DigestInit_ex:disabled for FIPS
    at new Hash (internal/crypto/hash.js:46:19)
    at Object.createHash (crypto.js:115:10)
    at NgccConfiguration.computeHash (/home/b73134/displays/amp-workspace/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/packages/configuration.js:216:29)
    at new NgccConfiguration (/home/b73134/displays/amp-workspace/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/packages/configuration.js:108:30)
    at Object.mainNgcc (/home/b73134/displays/amp-workspace/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/main.js:46:22)
    at /home/b73134/displays/amp-workspace/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/main-ngcc.js:34:53
    at step (/home/b73134/displays/amp-workspace/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.next (/home/b73134/displays/amp-workspace/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at /home/b73134/displays/amp-workspace/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

## Openssl Version

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020
```

## Angular CLI Info

```sh
Angular CLI: 9.1.5
Node: 14.15.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 9.1.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.901.5
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.901.13
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.901.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.901.5
@angular-devkit/core               9.1.12
@angular-devkit/schematics         9.1.12
@angular/cdk                       9.2.4
@angular/cli                       9.1.5
@angular/flex-layout               9.0.0-beta.31
@angular/material                  9.2.4
@angular/material-moment-adapter   <error>
@ngtools/webpack                   9.1.5
@schematics/angular                9.1.12
@schematics/update                 0.901.5
ng-packagr                         9.1.5
rxjs                               6.6.2
typescript                         3.8.3
webpack                            4.42.0
```

Comment: Followed the instructions to use a custom webpack configuration
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/12/09/angular-webpack

Updated the hash function to sha256, and could see the hash value changes on ng serve
https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputhashfunction

It progressed further, but I see the same error at 93%
93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin main.js generate SourceMap(node:66221) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: error:060800C8:digital envelope routines:EVP_DigestInit_ex:disabled for FIPS
    at new Hash (internal/crypto/hash.js:46:

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Angular/Webpack, by default, is using md4/md5 for it's hashing algorithms which is not supported in FIPS environment. I had to use custom webpack settings to set the hash algorithm. There are some items where webpack itself hard codes to md4/md5, in those instances I had to comment out the configuration all together

What I did to get everything to work

- npm install --save-dev @angular-builders/custom-webpack@9.2.0
- create file "custom-webpack.config.js"
- update angular.json to use custom-webpack.config.js

Update angular.json to use custom-webpack.config.js

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
    "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
        ",
        ...

  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
    ...

  "test": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma",
```

custom-webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin({
      hashFunction: 'sha256'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    hashFunction: 'sha256',
  },
  optimization: {
    concatenateModules: false // Hardcoded to md4, have to disable
  }
}
```

Update angular.json production configuration. These two items are hardcoded to md4/md5 in webpack so I had to turn it off

- "outputHashing": "none"
- Remove entry "extractCss"

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of JS files in node_modules/webpack that are hard coded to md4. To get around those files, downloaded patch-package module which creates patch files of updated files in node_modules and applies them on npm install, update, etc...

Comment: Hi there. This new answer of yours is and edit (addition) to your previous answer rather than a new answer on its own. Would you care to merge them?